# Performance of UPDATE and two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have 2 tables, **TABLE1** and **TABLE2** each with several million rows. A column in **TABLE1** is updated based on IDs with a certain feature in **TABLE2**.

Can someone please explain to me why the second solution below takes 30 seconds, while the first solution does not even finish after 5 hours? I thought that code with the need to create a new table and deleting it after the update is finished is not a good coding style. But it is so much faster in this case. Is there a recommendation?

1.) **Takes forever:**
    `UPDATE TABLE1 SET  TABLE1.MYCOLUMN  = 1 WHERE TABLE1.ID IN (SELECT distinct(ID) FROM TABLE2 where .... );`

2.) **Takes 30 seconds:**

`CREATE TABLE TABLE3 AS (SELECT distinct(ID) FROM TABLE2 where ....); 
ALTER TABLE TABLE3 ADD primary key(ID);
UPDATE TABLE1 SET  TABLE1.MYCOLUMN  = 1 WHERE TABLE1.ID IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE3);`

Comment: Are your column indexed ?

Comment: How many distinct ids compared to actual ids returned from the subquery?

Answer (score 0):

In general, `WHERE IN (some query returning lots of rows)` performs badly. Although the optimizer should be able to convert it to a join, often it doesn't, meaning the entire result set has to be stored in memory and won't be indexed.

Try using mysql's multiple table update syntax:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
SET TABLE1.MYCOLUMN  = 1
```

Make sure there's an index on `TABLE1.ID` and one on `TABLE2.ID`.